# How to count repeating value inside an array of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript, reduce

```
const vehicle = [
  {
    a: [
      {
        vehicle_name: "Toyota",
        color: "black"
      },
      {
        vehicle_name: "Toyota",
        color: "red"
      },
      {
        vehicle_name: "Ford",
        color: "yellow"
      },
      {
        vehicle_name: "Toyota",
        color: "white"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    b: [
      {
        vehicle_name: "Honda",
        color: "black"
      },
      {
        vehicle_name: "Honda",
        color: "red"
      },
      {
        vehicle_name: "Ford",
        color: "yellow"
      },
      {
        vehicle_name: "Toyota",
        color: "white"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Given the array of obj above, My goal is to get the total number of vehicle in each key.
Note: if the vehicle_name is repeated it should only count as 1.
Expected Output:

```
const result = [
  {
    a: {
      count: 2
    }
  },
  {
    b: {
      count: 3
    }
  }
]
```

Explanation: The count of key a => is 2 because although it have 4 vehicles but Toyota is repeated so it only count as 1. Same goes in key b => the count is 3 because it has three different name(Honda, Ford, Toyota)

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specifically isn't working with your attempt? Please [edit] your question to include this info. Do both your objects in your array have different keys (`a` and `b`)? Usually, these would be the same across all objects in your array (so just double checking that they actually are different).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` to iterate the objects in `vehicle`, then `Object.entries` to iterate those objects, using `reduce` to count the unique vehicles seen in the objects in each array value:

```js
const vehicle = [
  {
  a: [
    { vehicle_name: "Toyota", color: "black" },
    { vehicle_name: "Toyota", color: "red" },
    { vehicle_name: "Ford", color: "yellow" },
    { vehicle_name: "Toyota", color: "white" }
  ]
  },
  {
  b: [
    { vehicle_name: "Honda", color: "black" },
    { vehicle_name: "Honda", color: "red" },
    { vehicle_name: "Ford", color: "yellow" },
    { vehicle_name: "Toyota", color: "white" }
    ]
  }
]

const result =
  vehicle.map(o => Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(o).map(([k, a]) => [k, { count : 
      a.reduce((acc, { vehicle_name }) => {
        if (!(vehicle_name in acc)) {
          acc[vehicle_name] = 1
          acc.count++
        }
        return acc
      }, { count: 0 }).count }
    ])
  )
)

console.log(result)
```